# Dojo widget id is already registered

Tags: javascript, dojo

I read about 10 errors like this but nowhere I found a solution.

I run this code in dojo:

```
this.myHeader = registry.byId("banner");
// returns 'undefined'

if(!this.myHeader) {
    this.myHeader = new Header({ 
        primaryBannerType: 'thin' 
    }, "banner");  
}
```

My config is `parseOnLead: true` but I do not parse any file widget manually so I think this is no problem.
- I check whether the widget is already loaded
- I do not parse the widget twice

why I get this error?

```
Tried to register widget with id==banner but that id is already registered
```

thanks

Comment: Hey Alexander could you share some more code?

Comment: Does "Header" contains sub widgets ?  which ID is reported to be already registered ?

Comment: `Tried to register widget with id==banner but that id is already registered`

the Header is a widget from the IDX Toolkit so that should work

Comment: The Header is a Part of my `NavigationWidget` wich is loaded to every page as navigation bar. To avoid multiple registering of the widget I tried to get the widget from the registry and use this instead and just `startup()` this

Comment: create fiddle or just add complete code so that we can reproduce the same issue...

Comment: if your config has `parseOnLead: true`, check your templates, probably another widget with that id

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I searched through all files and found a rudimental id in another div. It s not used but it also was called 'header" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have no other DOM elements with the same ID on your page.

I usually use the following utility script, which can spot this kind of problem very quickly and saving some time when debugging.

You can just copy and paste in your developer console (it is a self invoking function).

```js
 (function() {
   var elms = document.body.querySelectorAll('*[id]'),
       ids = [];
   for (var i = 0, len = elms.length; i < len; i++) {
     if (ids.indexOf(elms[i].id) === -1) {
       ids.push(elms[i].id);
     } else {
       console.log('Multiple IDs #' + elms[i].id);
     }
   }
 })();
```

```html
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
```

Also on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/m92pdje4/

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I already found a solution by chance. I just renamed many of my ids and hoped to solve the problem this way ^^

Comment: @alex great! I am glad my answer helped you out. If you found my answer  was useful please accept it or up-voting my answer :) - To accept an answer click tick icon on its left side.